# refactor class to use generics in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I want to refactor this:

```
public class X {
   String get()....
}
```

to

```
public class X<T> {
   T get()...
}
```

... And then the instances in the code would be changed to

```
X<String> x = ....
```

Is that possible in IntelliJ?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generify-refactoring.html

Comment: generify doesn't work as I want it, because what it does is that it changes every raw type in a particular class, rather all the instances to a particular type when refactoring a class to a generic type, which is what I need.

Comment: In case someone else lands here searching for how to perform this refactoring, it seems to be done with Class signature changing, but only partially, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/change-signature.html#change_class_signature_refactoring